# python sort django models by value in json field

Tags: python, json, sorting, django-models

I make a query for some models, and return an evaluated list from the resulting queryset object.

One of the fields in this model is a text field that contains a json string.  I want to sort the list of models based on the value of a key in the json.

Example JSON:

```
meta_data = "{'V1': {
               'key': key,
               'timestamp': timestamp,
               'current': True,
               'conversion_type': conversion_type,
               'filename': filename},
             'V2': {
               'key': key,
               'timestamp': timestamp,
               'current': False,
               'conversion_type': conversion_type,
               'filename': filename},
             'notes': []}"
```

The key/value pairs are either A.) a version (V1, V2, etc.) with key, timestamp, etc. or B.) notes.  I need to ignore the notes, find the Version with current=True, and use the timestamp of that version to sort by.

I'm trying this:

```
def get_version_created_time(meta_data):
    meta_data = json.loads(meta_data)
    for key, value in meta_data.iteritems():
        try:
            if value['current'] == True:
                return value['timestamp']
        except KeyError:
            pass

list_of_models.sort(key=get_version_created_time(operator.attrgetter('meta_data')))
```

but my function expects a string, and operator.attrgetter('meta_data') is not a string. How should I get the meta_data field json string, so I can pass it to my function to find the timestamp of the current version, or what's the right way to sort a list of models in the way I've described.

Thanks,

Comment: I wish I knew why my question was down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution: my function being passed as the sort key just needed to assume the correct argument type, which is a model, and call Django's model_to_dict so I can pull the json out of the field and look through it for the value I wanted.

```
def get_version_created_time(item):
    u = model_to_dict(item)
    meta_data = json.loads(u['meta_data'])
    for key, value in meta_data.iteritems():
        try:
            if value['current'] == True:
                return value['timestamp']
        except TypeError:
            pass

res_sorted = sorted(res, key=get_version_created_time, reverse=True)
```